# Kubuntu 20 system performance problems

Tags: kde, performance, services

working in Kubuntu 20 I periodically have big problems with performance : my system practically
stops and I have to waite for some period to resume my work:
More details about my Laptop and OS :

Running top command I see :

```
top - 09:36:02 up  1:20,  1 user,  load average: 9.90, 12.13, 9.24
Tasks: 281 total,   3 running, 278 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 54.1 us,  2.6 sy,  0.1 ni, 42.6 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7868.7 total,    695.2 free,   6537.1 used,    636.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2055.2 total,    123.8 free,   1931.4 used.   1023.8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                    
   4645 postgres  20   0 2870868   2.0g      4 S 100.0  26.5  77:46.78 kswapd0                                                                                                                                    
   4634 master    20   0 2936404   2.0g      4 S  99.3  26.5  77:03.22 kswapd0                                                                                                                                    
   1413 root      20   0  394084  54188  24784 R   6.3   0.7   3:45.59 Xorg                                                                                                                                       
   4259 master    20   0 2897444  60544  47876 R   5.6   0.8   5:04.03 kwin_x11                                                                                                                                   
   4386 master    20   0  357376  39256  25736 S   5.6   0.5   0:16.73 konsole                                                                                                                                    
  13146 master    20   0    7216   5700   3496 S   4.0   0.1   0:01.27 htop                                                                                                                                       
   4303 master    20   0  698316  11784   3332 S   2.0   0.1   1:55.60 audacious                                                                                                                                  
   1461 mysql     20   0 2718356  30808      0 S   0.7   0.4   0:47.92 mysqld                                                                                                                                     
   4008 master     9 -11 1412560   4856   3308 S   0.7   0.1   2:15.42 pulseaudio                                                                                                                                 
   4010 master    39  19  599640  18312   2252 S   0.7   0.2   0:58.10 tracker-miner-f                                                                                                                            
   4325 master    20   0  757580  12072   5012 S   0.7   0.1   0:28.28 ktorrent                                                                                                                                   
   5052 mongodb   20   0 2655964  33524      0 S   0.7   0.4   1:28.78 mongod                                                                                                                                     
     28 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:02.04 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                
   1527 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:42.88 irq/43-nvidia                                                                                                                              
   5209 master    20   0 6818108   1.3g     28 S   0.3  16.4  12:14.31 java                                                                                                                                       
  12347 master    20   0   17016    948      0 R   0.3   0.0   0:01.06 top                                                                                                                                        
  13127 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.04 kworker/1:3-events                                                                                                                         
      1 root      20   0  170908   8460   3708 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.72 systemd                                                                                                                                    
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                   
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                     
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                 
      5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns
```

I have worked with postgres priorly, but I removed all postgres packages
from my OS and now I have :

```
$ apt list --installed  postgres
Listing... Done
...
$ dpkg -s   postgres
dpkg-query: package 'postgres' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

So it is very strange to see postgres in listing of “top” coomand
“master” - that is name of current user

any ideas why so and how that can be fixed?

I have MSI GP70-2PE (GP702PE-426XUA) laptop :
https://prnt.sc/keAH_wqF18tV
https://prnt.sc/uCm6oUaZLDbL

```
$  uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
5.15.0-41-generic
x86_64
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8059236     6636260      196608      130344     1226368      998828
Swap:       2104476     1917244      187232

$  kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.12.8
KDE Frameworks: 5.68.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

After some tests I see that I have problems with performance(my OS pause for some period like 5-10 seconds)
if in my working Chrome browser(Google Chrome
Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)) I open several tabs.

Checking top command :

**ADDITIVE INFO :**

```
top - 09:51:45 up  3:14,  1 user,  load average: 7.34, 5.57, 5.23
Tasks: 301 total,   4 running, 297 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 61.6 us, 34.9 sy,  0.1 ni,  0.1 id,  1.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7868.7 total,    100.8 free,   7443.9 used,    324.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2055.2 total,      0.0 free,   2055.2 used.     52.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                    
    105 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  99.7   0.0  10:33.35 kswapd0                                                                                                                                    
   4594 postgres  20   0 2739796   2.0g      4 S  87.7  26.5 189:12.95 kswapd0                                                                                                                                    
   4600 master    20   0 2739796   2.0g      4 S  87.7  26.5 189:12.88 kswapd0                                                                                                                                    
  29923 master    20   0 1130.9g 152848  24240 R  28.2   1.9   0:35.17 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  31225 master    20   0 1129.9g 160792  27048 S  21.0   2.0   0:09.57 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  29466 master    20   0   32.6g 151208   9024 S  16.5   1.9   1:13.49 chrome                                                                                                                                     
   4228 master    20   0 2885688  39104  27792 S  11.3   0.5   9:50.37 kwin_x11                                                                                                                                   
  29509 master    20   0   32.6g 137592  33136 R  10.7   1.7   0:20.30 chrome                                                                                                                                     
   1451 root      20   0  393956  60220  32332 S   3.9   0.7   8:50.10 Xorg                                                                                                                                       
  29510 master    20   0   32.3g  33116  15532 S   2.9   0.4   0:07.57 chrome                                                                                                                                     
   4281 master    20   0  698440   8644   2088 S   2.6   0.1   3:26.09 audacious                                                                                                                                  
  29898 master    20   0 1129.9g 104228   4544 S   2.6   1.3   0:19.10 chrome                                                                                                                                     
   4350 master    20   0  680040   5704    452 S   2.3   0.1   0:34.55 ktorrent                                                                                                                                   
   1743 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1.3   0.0   1:16.11 irq/43-nvidia                                                                                                                              
  25729 master    20   0 6727456   1.2g     60 S   1.3  15.5  14:08.12 java                                                                                                                                       
   1456 mysql     20   0 2751124  36824      0 S   1.0   0.5   1:40.25 mysqld                                                                                                                                     
   3993 master     9 -11 1412560   3264   1996 S   1.0   0.0   2:03.77 pulseaudio                                                                                                                                 
   3995 master    39  19  679268  12188      0 S   1.0   0.2   1:29.31 tracker-miner-f                                                                                                                            
  29637 master    20   0 1129.9g 117124   8056 S   1.0   1.5   0:09.85 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  29660 master    20   0 1130.9g  58800   1804 S   1.0   0.7   0:05.92 chrome                                                                                                                                     
   7909 master    20   0  353096  14120   7556 S   0.6   0.2   0:13.65 konsole                                                                                                                                    
  29797 master    20   0 1129.9g  25512   1452 S   0.6   0.3   0:01.54 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  29950 master    20   0 1129.9g  93136  14672 S   0.6   1.2   0:16.82 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  31328 master    20   0 1129.9g  40128   5364 S   0.6   0.5   0:01.70 chrome                                                                                                                                     
    116 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:04.68 kworker/3:1H-kblockd                                                                                                                       
   1062 root      20   0   90708  16944      0 S   0.3   0.2   1:00.03 mount.ntfs-3g                                                                                                                              
   1318 root      20   0  263956    500      4 S   0.3   0.0   0:01.47 php-fpm8.1                                                                                                                                 
   1336 root      20   0 1495748   5960      0 S   0.3   0.1   0:08.47 containerd                                                                                                                                 
   4231 master    39  19  256.2g    992      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:02.30 baloo_file                                                                                                                                 
   4519 master    20   0  324384   1256      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:01.45 http.so                                                                                                                                    
  29464 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:01.22 kworker/2:2-events                                                                                                                         
  29538 master    20   0 1129.9g  19256   3312 S   0.3   0.2   0:00.47 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  29935 master    20   0 1129.9g  91480   4348 S   0.3   1.1   0:12.91 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  30655 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.57 kworker/0:0-events                                                                                                                         
  30750 master    20   0 1130.9g  68496   5088 S   0.3   0.9   0:05.18 chrome                                                                                                                                     
  31357 master    20   0   17000   1644    708 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.08 top                                                                                                                                        
      1 root      20   0  169504   1852    144 S   0.0   0.0   0:03.67 systemd                                                                                                                                    
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

I see several rows with “chrome”, but most of memory takes by
root,  postgres, master - in first 3 lines and I do not know how can I fix it ?

I tried to delete postgres user in command line, but I got error :

```
sudo deluser  postgres

Removing user `postgres' ...
Warning: group `postgres' has no more members.
userdel: user postgres is currently used by process 3976
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/sbin/userdel postgres' returned error code 8. Exiting.
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with George that your memory is low. But that doesn't explain the postgres service. So what does `systemctl status postgresql` say? If this systemd service is still present, you should disable it with `sudo systemctl disable postgresql.service` and report back

Answer (score 2):

The process `kswap0`, which manages virtual memory/swap, is taking using 2 CPU cores and might be the cause of the slowness.
Your system has used almost all of its RAM and its swap file as well (8GB RAM/695MB free, 2GB swap almost full).

```
top - 09:36:02 up  1:20,  1 user,  load average: 9.90, 12.13, 9.24
Tasks: 281 total,   3 running, 278 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 54.1 us,  2.6 sy,  0.1 ni, 42.6 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7868.7 total,    695.2 free,   6537.1 used,    636.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2055.2 total,    123.8 free,   1931.4 used.   1023.8 avail Mem 
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                    
   4645 postgres  20   0 2870868   2.0g      4 S 100.0  26.5  77:46.78 **kswapd0**                                                                                                                                    
   4634 master    20   0 2936404   2.0g      4 S  99.3  26.5  77:03.22 **kswapd0**
```

You could increase the swap file size to 8GB, from the current 2GB, which appears insufficient.
This assumes that you are already using a swap file (default Ubuntu setup) and that the `/swapfile` is referenced in `/etc/fstab`.

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm  /swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: 1) Any ideas what takes such big amount of data ? 2) Why I see postgres at top ?

Comment: Please look at ADDITIVE INFO